# Forcing HTTP Response to return Status 200 in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How do you force your requests to return status 200 except for serious cases where I return 500? Currently, I am running into the issue where my client keeps getting a status code of 411 (length not specified) and this is causing issues with my test framework.

Is there a way to manually specify your return status in maybe a Rails controller?

EDIT: More specifically I know that you can use

> :status

but where do I place that when using

> format.json { render :json=>final_obj}

to return a HTTP response after a POST?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

```
render status: 200, json: @controller.to_json
```

Comment: I think using :ok instead of the literal 200 is better. In case http changes and it becomes something else :)

Comment: @Purrell using variables instead of magic numbers is just good practice.

Answer (score 13):

I suppose this should answer your question, if I understood your question correctly.

Ruby 1.9.3

```
format.json { render json: final_obj, status: :ok }
```

Ruby 1.8.7

```
format.json { render :json => final_obj, :status => :ok }
```