# Ruby on Rails routes to controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, routes, view

As I understand it, routes will take you from a starting point to a controller, and an action. The action brings up the associated views; so what if I don't need any views for my controller, and just want to just call a controller's underlying method, without rendering the view or route.

Lets say I have a `FoodsController` with several methods, and there exists methods cake, pizza, and chips within that controller. Each one queries the database for a secret message and stores it in a variable, but the request for this is going to come from some other part of our application.

To accomplish this am I supposed to use a route for this or some kind of dot syntax such as `food.cake()`.

So I guess what I am trying to say is, hey "Server" go do this and come back to where you left off once its done.

Comment: check this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14806310/forcing-http-response-to-return-status-200-in-rails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controller are only for URL endpoints. For example if you hit `http://my.app/my_route`, you need to map the `my_route` part to a controller action in your `routes.rb` file. But what happens if you type this into your browser? You'll want to see something right? So you need to return some data (json, html, erc). You can use `render` for this.

This is different to writing 'normal' Ruby code, i.e. Ruby outside a web framework. Do you understand what a class is and how the following works?

```
class MyClass
  def initialize
  end
  def my_method
    puts "my_method_called"
  end
end

MyClass.new.my_method # => "my_method_called"
```

This is very basic Ruby and works in Rails as well, although there are some rules about where code needs to be written.

By the way, if you really want to make a controller action that renders nothing, just use:

```
render text: "", status: 204
return false
```

The status: 204 means "No Content".

Comment: So something like PostController.new.create... call class. then new for a new instance of class, lastly the method in the class?

Comment: The answer is no, but it's a good question. Controllers are sort of a special case in that you never instantiate them directly, all that happens behind the scenes when you type a url in. If you just want to make a helper method you can use anywhere, you could make it a class method on one of your models or write a new class/module in the `config/initializers/` folder.

Comment: Then if I can create a class in config/initializers or in the model then they can be accessed from other places why do we even have controllers. Why not just make one helper that does all the basic CRUD methods and just keep passing it a model when you want perform one of those methods in the class

Comment: It depens what you're making. If you're database-backed CLI, then yeah, there's no reason to have controllers. But a web app by definition is going to have HTTP requests, i.e. when you request some data with a URL you expect to get data back. this "request => response cycle" is the purpose of controllers. In regards to your "why not make one helper" question - I don't see any reason _not_ to do this but it's not a 'magic bullet' that addresses some fundamental shortcoming of Rails. Anyway, if you're sick of writing CRUD controllers, try using scaffold.

Answer (score 0):

You can use render json or text, if the method does not render anything, I think it should be private.

Comment: Ok so I want do call a method that doesn't have a view it should be in the private section?

Comment: If the method does not render a value or view so make it private, because its only used in the controller not for public.

Comment: If you don not want to change the view or the action, you can make an ajax and return json.

Answer (score 0):

In your example you could use the cake method in another controller like so:

```
cake = Food.cake
```

Please note that this method should live in the food model and not the controller, since you do not need a view.

Comment: Is the Food part calling the model or the controller? I was under the impression that you need to call the controller plural and model singular.