# Set http status code 201 to an API response in action controller rails

Tags: ruby, api, controller, ruby-on-rails-5, http-status-codes

I'm new to rails and I'm building a Rails app that will function as an API. Currently I don't have any models or database just an `Api::ProductController` controller:

```
class Api::ProductController < ApplicationController

  def create
    Rails.logger.info "product was created and the parameters are #{product_params[:name]}, #{product_params[:age]}"
  end

  private

  def product_params
    params.permit(:name, :age)
  end
end
```

. As I continue and wrote the request Rspec:

```
RSpec.describe Api::productsController, type: :request do

  it "creates a product" do
    post "/api/products", params: { name: "name", age: "22"}

    expect(response).to have_http_status(:created)
    expect(response.body).to include("product was successfully created.")
  end
end
```

But when I run the request rspec test on the command line I get the following error:

```
Failure/Error: expect(response).to have_http_status(:created)
       expected the response to have status code :created (201) but it was :no_content (204)
```

My question is how can I set the status code to :created (201)? is the Head method a good approach? any solution or guiding would be appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Forcing HTTP Response to return Status 200 in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14806310/forcing-http-response-to-return-status-200-in-rails)

Comment: @anothermh saw that post, but it was 6 years ago and not sure if it is still the same convention in rails 5

Answer (score 4):

It is common to return json presentation of created item.
Now there is no returning data from your action.

Try to use `render json: product_params.to_json, status: :created`

Comment: Add this piece of code into the create action? under the Rails.logger?

Answer (score 1):

```
  def create
    Rails.logger.info "product was created and the parameters are #{product_params[:name]}, #{product_params[:age]}"
    render status: :created
  end
```

Comment: this will pass the first test assertion but your second one will still fail, but I haven't provided a solution to that because your test for the body is wrong I think